# Apex class getting the product fields from pricebookentry where pricebook name ='Test'

Tags: apex, soql, pricebook, product, pricebookentry

We are having Product , Pricebookentry and pricebook in SFDC as a standard object. here pricebookentery is having look up to product and pricebook. 
so i want to get all the prodcuct fields which is associated with pricebook.

```
public class test123{

        Public test123(){
        List<PricebookEntry> pb = [select id, product2.name,Unitprice from Pricebookentry where pricebook2.name = 'Test'  ];
        system.debug('@@@@' +pb);

    }

  List<PricebookEntry> pb = [select id, product2.name,Unitprice from Pricebookentry where pricebook2.name = 'Test'  ];
```

this query is working in developer console getting all the values of priceboook and products. if you call from apex class its not working please see the log below .. please help to understand Not- pricebook and prodcut is not having any relationship.

> DEBUG|@@@@(PricebookEntry:{Id=01u28000007nkSJAAY,
>   Product2Id=01t28000001Fq7gAAC, UnitPrice=5000.00,
>   Pricebook2Id=01s2800000DF6PtAAL},
>   PricebookEntry:{Id=01u28000007nkSKAAY, Product2Id=01t28000001Fq7ZAAS,
>   UnitPrice=2300.00, Pricebook2Id=01s2800000DF6PtAAL},
>   PricebookEntry:{Id=01u28000007nkSLAAY, Product2Id=01t28000001Fq7YAAS,
>   UnitPrice=212.00, Pricebook2Id=01s2800000DF6PtAAL},
>   PricebookEntry:{Id=01u28000007nkSMAAY, Product2Id=01t28000001Fq7nAAC,
>   UnitPrice=1236.00, Pricebook2Id=01s2800000DF6PtAAL}

Comment: In debug log, you will always get the reference object Id. When you refer that value for assignments or for manipulation you will get that value in apex class. (pb[0].product2.Name it will give product name related to that price-book entry)

Comment: If your question is not about the fact that an Id is output in the debug log vs the `product2.name` please add a comment and I will remove the close vote. I suspect it is so you can validate by simply debugging `pb[0].product2.name` and see that the name is output as you would expect. See duplicates for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query

```
List<PriceBookEntry> lstpbe = [SELECT Product2.Id, Product2.Name
                               FROM PriceBookEntry 
                               WHERE Pricebook2Id IN (SELECT Id 
                                                      FROM PriceBook2 
                                                      WHERE Name = '<Your Price Book>')];
System.debug('lstpbe=' + JSON.serialize(lstpbe));
```

Comment: I do not think this would really help the OP understand what is going on.

Comment: I will wait for his update

Comment: Right, because the answer is solely for the OP and no-one else coming at a later time...And anyone looking is supposed to get from the code only answer the reason why the relationship data is not being displayed when you simply debug the query results like the OP did.

Comment: all the fields are coming but now I want to separate the product details from pricebookentry . like product id and name from that pricebooklist want to add it to product **list <produut2> prod {get;set;}**  like prod = lstpbe.product2. anyways to do that.